# how should I create a view function to take the date and time from the user?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm new into coding and I'm working at a Beauty Salon project where users can make an online appointment. I did a function where users can select the services they want to book and when they press the button they will go to another page and they should select the date and time for the appointment. I need a function to save the date and time and also to show the employee for that service(service has foreign key with employee).
Here is my code:

views.py

```
    template_name = 'services/rezervare.html'
    model = Service
    context_object_name = 'all_services'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('homepage')


def rezervare(request):
    all_services = Service.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'services/rezervare.html', {'all_services': all_services})


def rezerva_servicii(request):
    if request.POST and request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_user_id = request.user.id
        services_ids = [int(item) for item in dict(request.POST) if item != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken']
        for service_id in services_ids:
            serviciu = RezervareServicii(id_service_id=service_id, id_user=current_user_id)
            serviciu.save()
        all_employees = Employee.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'services/rezervare_programare.html', {'employees': all_employees})
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))



class RezervareProgramareView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'services/rezervare_programare.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['employees'] = Employee.objects.all()
        return context
```

models.py

```
class RezervareServicii(models.Model):
    id_service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id_user = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=9, default='draft')
    id_angajat = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


class Programare(models.Model):
    angajat = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_ora = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Programare cu {self.angajat.username} la {self.data_ora}"
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from services import views
from services.views import rezerva_servicii

urlpatterns = [
    path('creare_serviciu/', views.ServiceCreateView.as_view(), name='creare-serviciu'),
    path('lista_servicii/', views.ServiceListView.as_view(), name='lista-servicii'),
    path('update_serviciu/<int:pk>', views.ServiceUpdateView.as_view(), name='update-serviciu'),
    path('sterge_serviciu/<int:pk>', views.ServiceDeleteView.as_view(), name='sterge-serviciu'),
    path('detalii_serviciu/<int:pk>', views.ServiceDetailView.as_view(), name='detalii-serviciu'),
    path('rezervare/', views.Rezervare.as_view(), name='rezervare'),
    path('rezervare/programare/', rezerva_servicii, name='rezervare-programare'),
    path('rezervare/programare/succes/', views.RezervareProgramareView.as_view(), name='rezervare-programare-succes')
]
```

I'm stuck in this problem and idk how to continue it... if anyone can help me and also correct my code I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.